# Determine if it is countable or uncountable

Tags: analysis

Determine if it is countable or uncountable
The set $E$ of all circle in $R$$^2$ with centers at rational coordinate points and positive rational radius.

I have no idea about this type of question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if you can find a surjective mapping from a countable set to the set $E$ you are looking at, you will prove the set $E$ is countable.

Try finding a surjection from $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q_+$ to $E$.

Comment: Don't you need $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ to $E$? As you have a rational radius as well.

Comment: Correct. Even more correct, it's $\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q_+$

Comment: Still not 100% understand... How about the $R$$^2$?? Is it mean real number? So it is uncountable??

Comment: No, because you can't have a circle with the center at $(\sqrt 2, 5)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**:

1) If sets $A$ and $B$ are countable then their cartesian product $A\times B$ is countable.

2) Note that every element of $E$ is represented by a triple $(x,y,r)$ with $x,y\in \mathbb Q$ and $r\in \mathbb Q^{+}$